# Linking to my login page/sign up page on homepage with rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Disclaimer: this is a question from a Python coder attempting to learn the Ruby on Rails framework.

So I have a navbar for the homepage of my website and within the navbar I have the following:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
    <li class="hidden">
        <a href="#page-top"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#apr">APR</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#login">Log In</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I incorporate the following from my authentication views:

```
<%= link_to "Sign Up", sign_up_path %> or
<%= link_to "Log In", log_in_path %>
```

I have a css for 'a' as well as the "page-scroll" class. So I want to keep these.

So for the following method just targeting the Log In:

```
<li>
   <a class="page-scroll"><%= link_to "Log In", log_in_path %></a>
</li>
```

I have the following problem:

[image]

In essence, it pushes the log-in button down. Simply by the addition of `<%= %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking for this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   ...

   <li>
     <%= link_to "Sign Up", sign_up_path, class: "page-scroll" %>
   </li>

   <li>
     <%= link_to "Log In", log_in_path, class: "page-scroll" %>
   </li>

   ...
</ul>
```

Have a look at the Api reference for [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), it has a bunch of useful options.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfect. Very simple too, should have been able to work this out.